# exporting global variable in tee process substitution subshells

Tags: bash, tee, process-substitution

```
command | tee >(var="$(command1)") >(var1="$(command2)")
echo "$var $var1"
```

Also tried moreutils pee

```
command | pee 'var="$(command)"' 'var1="$(command2)"'
```

Also tried export
command | tee >(export var="$(command1)") >(var1="$(command2)")

**Problem 1**
My need is use one command output and use it by multiple commands as their input.

**Problem2**

```
function() { Array=("$1"); }
function String
```

Above works

```
command | parallel -I %% function %%
```

Above not working array is not  set
Is there any workaround. Please Help.

Command output:

```
1 word
2 word
3 word
4 word
1 string
2 string
3 string
4 string
```

How can i set two associative array one with word and othet with string from piped output??
Array1[1]=word
Array1[2]=word

Array2[1]=string
Array2[2]=string

Comment: How do we tell apart what entries go into tho first array and what entries goes into the second array? Why do you want to use an associative array if the indexes are consecutive integers?

Comment: `function() { whatever; }` doesn't actually work in the Bash versions I tried (3.2, 4.4 and the git devel version from some time back), since `function` is a keyword. `function function { whatever; }` would, but you'd need to escape/quote the name to call it...

Comment: @ilkkachu I think the user meant "function" to be a placeholder for some function name.

Comment: @user414574: as you can see, it creates confusion to use bogus names that are also keywords in your code.  Can you replace 'function' and 'command' with realistic examples?

Answer (score 1):

Like @they said, the process substitutions run in subshells, so assignments there aren't visible to the main shell. Same goes for `pee` and `parallel`, while at least the latter can use exported functions, it still starts a distinct shell where the code runs.

You could also use a temporary file for the *results* as a workaround, which might be worth it if the input data is longer than the results are. E.g.:

```
seq 10 | tee >(wc -l > lines) >(wc -c > chars) > /dev/null
lines=$(< lines)
chars=$(< chars)
```

Or maybe with

```
tmp1=$(mktemp)
tmp2=$(mktemp)
seq 10 | tee >(wc -l > "$tmp1") >(wc -c > "$tmp2") > /dev/null
lines=$(< "$tmp1")
chars=$(< "$tmp2")
rm -f "$tmp1" "$tmp2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you intend to set the values of variables so that they are visible in the outermost shell of the shown code.

In all the examples you show, the variable assignment and `export` are performed in subshells (or in child processes).  Inside the subshell, the variable is set and could be used as usual. Still, when the subshell terminates, the variable is lost, no matter whether it's a shell variable or an environment variable ("an exported shell variable").  A subshell will never be able to affect the environment of its parent shell.

You would be able to get by by using a temporary file here:

```bsh
some-command >tmpfile

var1=$(other-command1 <tmpfile)
var2=$(other-command2 <tmpfile)

rm -f tmpfile
```

Or, if `some-command` is trivial (using only shell built-in utilities, minimal resources, and does not produce copious amounts of output):

```bsh
var1=$( some-command | other-command1 )
var2=$( some-command | other-command2 )
```

---

Reading newline-delimited data into an array, if that is what you are trying to do, is done using `readarray` in `bash`:

```bsh
readarray -t array < <( some-command )
```

However, this is likely not what you would want to do if the command `some-command` produces a lot of output.  In that yase, you are more likely to want to process the data in a pipeline using `awk`, Python or some other language.

Comment: No sir. Its aboyt using same output as input for two commands witthout intermediat file and without runnning same command two times as it is heavy on resources

Comment: @DaichiAsh This is exactly the issue I'm addressing. You will not be able to do variable assignments in subshells or in child processes, and have them affect the calling shell. The way to do that is by using a temporary file as I have shown.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to create associative array on this case just like you described.above. i can anyhow fotmat to command output as two columns and so how can i store both column as associative array

Comment: @DaichiAsh If you have clarifications of the question, please update the question.  Consider showing a representative sample of the input, and exactly what you want to achieve with it.

Comment: @DaichiAsh Let me clarify my previous comment: To be able to show how to use an associative array to store the data from a file, I need to know what the data looks like. Consider updating the question with a representative sample of data, and with a description of what the end result that you are trying to achieve is given that data.

Comment: added the data to be set in array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133495/discussion-between-daichi-ash-and-they).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `parset` with `--pipe --tee`:

```
mkfifo myfifo
command > myfifo &
env_parset var,var1 --pipe --tee ::: command1 command2 < myfifo
echo "$var $var1"
```

Example:

```
command() { seq 10000; }
command1() { wc -l; }
command2() { wc -c; }
mkfifo myfifo
command > myfifo &
env_parset var,var1 --pipe --tee ::: command1 command2 < myfifo
echo "$var $var1"
```

If `command1` and `command2` are exported, you can use `parset` instead:

```
export -f command1 command2
mkfifo myfifo
command > myfifo &
parset var,var1 --pipe --tee ::: command1 command2 < myfifo
echo "$var $var1"
```

If your `command1` and `command2` are the same command with different options:

```
command > myfifo &
parset var,var1 --pipe --tee wc {} ::: -c -l < myfifo
echo "$var $var1"
```

If you want the output in an array:

```
command > myfifo &
parset arr --pipe --tee wc {} ::: -c -l < myfifo
echo "${arr[0]} ${arr[1]} ${arr[2]}"
```

If you want the output in an associative array:

```
typeset -A myassoc
command > myfifo &
parset myassoc --pipe --tee wc {} ::: -c -l < myfifo
echo "${myassoc[-c]} ${myassoc[-l]}"
```

As others have pointed out: You cannot use `|` to pipe data into `parset`/`parallel` because that would spawn `parset`/`parallel` in a subshell. This is why you need the fifo trick.

If your shell permits, you can also:

```
typeset -A myassoc
parset myassoc --pipe --tee wc {} ::: -c -l < <(command)
echo "${myassoc[-c]} ${myassoc[-l]}"
```

For more details see:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html